Nodejs: Error: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-ses'
While spinning up a nodejs app on an Ubuntu 22.04.4 machine, I'm facing this issue:
back-app-1  | [1] 2024-04-25T09:20:57.938Z error    Error: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-ses'
back-app-1  | [1] Require stack:
back-app-1  | [1] - /usr/src/app/app/services/send-mail.js
back-app-1  | [1] - /usr/src/app/app/api/authentication/authentication.controller.js
back-app-1  | [1] - /usr/src/app/app/api/authentication/authentication.routes.js
back-app-1  | [1] - /usr/src/app/app/api/router.js
back-app-1  | [1] - /usr/src/app/app/express.js
back-app-1  | [1] - /usr/src/app/app/server.js
back-app-1  | [1] - /usr/src/app/bin/www
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
back-app-1  | [1]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app/services/send-mail.js:2:13)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
back-app-1  | [1]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app/api/authentication/authentication.controller.js:7:22)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
back-app-1  | [1]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app/api/authentication/authentication.routes.js:4:20)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
back-app-1  | [1]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)

And this is the header of the file where it is used:
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const aws = require("@aws-sdk/client-ses");
const { defaultProvider } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node");
const SEND_MAIL = Symbol('SEND_MAIL');
const ses = new aws.SES({
  apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
  region: "eu-west-3",
  defaultProvider,
});

Relevant package.json part:
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.451.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node": "^3.451.0",
    ...
  }

The app is dockerized: packages are installed inside the container using npm ci.
Is there anything I can do to fix this?
More:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html
https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/
node: v20.5.1
npm: 10.5.2

Feels like there's information missing here which would help resolve this - how is your app being spun up? Is @aws-sdk/client-ses defined in your package.json if packages are installed as part of the app start, or is the package in your node_modules directory if it is copied from elsewhere?
Are there related error messages in the logs when the app is being started apart from the runtime error above?

You can directly install aws-sdk by running command npm i aws-sdk and then you can configure SES.
Suggestion:- you can directly use aws-sdk to send mail without using smtp as the provides several api for sending mail.
I am using aws-sdk APIs to send mail not SMTP. Here is the code which works for me.
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "your-aws-region" });
var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
.sendTemplatedEmail(params)
.promise();


In your case you can install aws-sdk and the you can easily configure ses.

  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  const aws = require("aws-sdk");
  const { defaultProvider } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-provider- 
  node");
  const SEND_MAIL = Symbol('SEND_MAIL');
  const ses = new aws.SES({
    apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
    region: "eu-west-3",
    defaultProvider,
  });

